# Rails3 – How do I make a custom Helper available to controllers And Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given the custom helper file in app/helpers/url_helper.rb

```
module UrlHelper
  ...
end
```

How do I make it accessible in all controllers and in all views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place it in ApplicationController (not a helper) and declare `helper_method :method_name`.

Comment: You mean that instead of using a separate file for global helpers I put them on the application controller?

Comment: You could define them in a module and include them into ApplicationController. What I'm saying is that a method contained in a helper cannot be used in a controller; however, a method in a controller (or in a module that is included in a controller) can be made available to the views and helpers using `helper_method`.

Answer (score 12):

Or... include them into your controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include UrlHelper
end
```

Comment: is that supposed to work in Rails 4 ? Because it doesn't work for me. The include does work, but the views don't have access to the methods.

Comment: @Michael Yes, it works. It's plain `ruby`, nevermind the `framework` or its `version`. Use `include` for instance methods and `extend` for class methods.