# Using /lib/ Subdirectories in Rails - for View Content

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is an evolving issue related to a previous posting I made...

I am playing around some - to try to learn how the `/lib/` directory in Rails works - and how to reference variables defined in the `/lib/` directory for use in a view.

I have a file called `helloworld.rb` and it's saved in a `/lib/hellotest/` directory in Rails.

The `helloworld.rb` file has the following code:

```
module HelloWorld
  def hello
    @howdy = "Hello World!"
  end
end
```

I want to be able to display the results of this method on a view called `index.html.erb`, so I include the following code in the `index_helper.erb` file:

```
module IndexHelper
  require 'helloworld'
end
```

I have learned that I need to include the following line of code in the `/config/application.rb` file:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib/hellotest/)
```

Also, I include the following code on the view `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= @howdy %>
```

I think I may have found something that is causing problems. I didn't want to load the entire `/lib/` directory at startup so I put the file in a subdirectory called `/lib/hellotest/`. I've read there are some issues with how Rails interprets module/class naming conventions in the lib folder, but I can't quite figure it out. I see a good resource regarding this possible solution to my problem on [William B Harding's Blog](http://www.williambharding.com/blog/technology/rails-3-autoload-modules-and-classes-in-production/), on point 2 - but I can't quite get my arms around this solution as it pertains to my problem.

Any advice please?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, follow the conventional naming for modules and classes (as described in the [link](http://www.williambharding.com/blog/technology/rails-3-autoload-modules-and-classes-in-production/) you provided). Rename `helloworld.rb` to `hello_world.rb`, move it into `lib`, and change your `autoload_paths` to:

```
 config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib/)
```

Finally, change `require 'hello_world'` to `require 'hello_world'` in your `IndexHelper` module. It should then load normally.

Comment: Using your suggestion - I think I'm getting closer, but the results still don't show up on the view. Is there something different I should be doing on the actual view?

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that part of the question. First thing, never use an extension which doesn't match the content of the file. You shouldn't be using .erb for a file with Ruby code in it, it should have the extension .rb. But actually there is no need for that file, you can include the `HelloWorld` module directly in `ApplicationController`, and then add a line `helper_method :hello` to make the `hello` method available in your views.

Comment: For reference, here are the [docs on `helper_method`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method), and a related [SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455583/rails3-how-do-i-make-a-custom-helper-available-to-controllers-and-views).

Comment: The filename issue above was a typo in my posting, but correct in my application.

I also had to change the method name to match the name of the required file:

- method in the `/lib/hello_world.rb` file to `def hello_world`.
- helper_method to `helper_method :hello_world`, and changed the View `<%= hello_world %>`.

There must be a requirement in Rails for the method to match the filename? 

I also found that the `config.autoload_paths` line wasn't necessary due to the `require hello_world` line in the `ApplicationController`.

Thank you again for your help! I'm starting to understand better.

Comment: Yes that's something I meant to mention, just didn't have time. Your files have to match the namespaces of your classes/modules, otherwise they won't get loaded. So if your class is named `HelloWorld` then the filename must be `hello_world.rb`, and if you have a sublcass `HelloWorld::SomeClass` the filename and directory also have to match, so the file should be in `hello_world/some_class.rb` (or in `hello_world.rb` itself together with the parent class). SO question on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074830/adding-lib-to-config-autoload-paths-in-rails-3-does-not-autoload-my-module